# how to schedule a background service between certain hours android

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I have a service that tracks the location of the user periodically.
I want this service to run only during working hours, so I want it to start at 9h and to stop at 18h.

I'm starting the service with an `AlarmManager` with this code

```
        Intent syncIntent = new Intent(AlarmService.this, TrackingService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AlarmService.this, 0, syncIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);
```

What should i do to schedule an alarm to stop the service at 18h ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register a `BroadcastReceiver` and create a `PendingIntent` for it using `getReceiver()`. In its `onReceive()` method call `stopService()` on the running `Service` instance. Hope this helps.

Comment: So i create another alarmManager that calls this BroadcastReceiver ?

Comment: @DanyY, You just schedule another task with AlarmManager, calling setRepeating() once again with a different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted you can set a single alarm using `set()` instead of `setRepeating()`. Then in your broadcast receiver you can check current time when alarm is received. If it is withing business hours (9 to 6) then you set another single alarm in your receiver. If it is not between 9 am and 6 pm then you schedule an alarm to 9 am tomorrow.